# fetching a file using wget with https hangs

Tags: wget

I have been fetching a file on a raspberry pi with the following command:

```
wget http://services.wlw.winlink.org/listings/RmsPactorListing.aspx?serviceCodes=PUBLIC
```

the link now maps to an https location, but wget hangs:

```
wget http://services.wlw.winlink.org/listings/RmsPactorListing.aspx?serviceCodes=PUBLIC
--2018-07-26 22:17:40--  
http://services.wlw.winlink.org/listings/RmsPactorListing.aspx? serviceCodes=PUBLIC
Resolving services.wlw.winlink.org (services.wlw.winlink.org)... 
104.27.129.143, 104.27.128.143, 2400:cb00:2048:1::681b:8
08f, ...
Connecting to services.wlw.winlink.org 
(services.wlw.winlink.org)|104.27.129.143|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: 
https://cms.winlink.org:444/listings/RmsPactorListing.aspx 
[following]
--2018-07-26 22:17:41--  
https://cms.winlink.org:444/listings/RmsPactorListing.aspx
Resolving cms.winlink.org (cms.winlink.org)... 52.55.74.23, 
52.205.46.246
Connecting to cms.winlink.org 
(cms.winlink.org)|52.55.74.23|:444...
```

I'm guessing the change to https is causing the problem, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.  If I use the new link in the wget command, I get the same hang.

```
$ wget https://cms.winlink.org:444/listings/RmsPactorListing.aspx?serviceCodes=PUBLIC
--2018-07-26 22:34:43--  
https://cms.winlink.org:444/listings/RmsPactorListing.asp?serviceCodes=PUBLIC
Resolving cms.winlink.org (cms.winlink.org)... 52.205.46.246, 
52.55.74.23
Connecting to cms.winlink.org 
(cms.winlink.org)|52.205.46.246|:444...
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you get when you do `wget https://cms.winlink.org:444/listings/RmsPactorListing.aspx -O downloaded_file.txt`? Also, if you do `telnet cms.winlink.org 444` from command line, do you get a `Escape character is '^]'` prompt?

Comment: In both cases suggested, I get the same hang (until timeout)

Comment: Do you have a firewall? It is possible something on your side might be blocking access to port 444. If you or your acquaintances are familiar with tcpdump or  wireshark, you might be able to do packet capture and see where you see silence.

Comment: Thanks - it is working on the raspberry pi (spelling error).  But it is hanging on a google cloud platform instance - I'll have to find out if google is blocking port 444.

Comment: It’s likely that you’ll have to put a rule to allow traffic to/from that host and port on google cloud instance

Comment: Any hints on how to add such a rule?

Comment: I don’t know enough about Google cloud. Delete this question and create a question on https://serverfault.com. You are likely to get server-centric help there.